# Is there a countifs function in python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, countif

I have a dataframe

```
df.head(9)

+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+
| session_id |   Enter     |    Exit     | Difference | User_id |    date     | Buyer | Seller | Non_buyer_seller |
+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+
| a          |       43770 |       43770 | 0:00:00    |       1 | 01/Nov/2019 |     1 |      0 |                0 |
| b          | 43770.79991 | 43770.79994 | 0:00:02    |       2 | 01/Nov/2019 |     1 |      0 |                0 |
| c          |  43770.5634 | 43770.56351 | 0:00:09    |       3 | 01/Nov/2019 |     0 |      0 |                1 |
| d          |  43770.5525 |  43770.5528 | 0:00:25    |       4 | 01/Nov/2019 |     1 |      0 |                0 |
| e          | 43770.33724 | 43770.33726 | 0:00:01    |       4 | 01/Nov/2019 |     1 |      0 |                0 |
| f          | 43770.65617 | 43770.65623 | 0:00:05    |       5 | 01/Nov/2019 |     0 |      0 |                1 |
| g          | 43770.54055 | 43770.54093 | 0:00:32    |       6 | 01/Nov/2019 |     0 |      0 |                1 |
| h          | 43770.54203 | 43770.54281 | 0:01:07    |       7 | 01/Nov/2019 |     0 |      0 |                1 |
| i          | 43770.64442 | 43770.64478 | 0:00:31    |       8 | 01/Nov/2019 |     0 |      1 |                0 |
+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+-------+--------+------------------+
```

I used to use countifs in excels to count the session like this

```
Buyers_0-to-1 min : =COUNTIFS($G:$G,1, $D$2:$D$671746,">=00:00:00",$D$2:$D$671746,"<=00:01:00")
Buyers_1.1-to-5 min : =COUNTIFS($G:$G,1, $D$2:$D$671746,">=00:01:01",$D$2:$D$671746,"<=00:05:00")

Sellers_0-to-1 min : =COUNTIFS($H:$H,1, $D$2:$D$671746,">=00:00:00",$D$2:$D$671746,"<=00:01:00")
Non_buyer_sellers_0to-1 min : =COUNTIFS($I:$I,1, $D$2:$D$671746,">=00:00:00",$D$2:$D$671746,"<=00:01:00")
```

So how can I do the same in python for my data frame.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As Lpython has already answered the question, You can use `np.sum` like this np.sum(df[col] > x)

Answer (score 0):

To perform the first COUNTIF you listed, you can try this.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Difference': ["00:00:00", "00:00:02", "00:00:09", "00:00:25", "00:00:01", "00:00:05", "00:00:32", "00:01:07", "00:00:31"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# 'Difference' column to timedelta
df['Difference'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Difference'])

# Conditional sum statement
df[(df.Difference >= "00:00:00") & (df.Difference <= "00:01:00")].sum() 

Difference   00:01:45
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I have assumed that the times are stored as a string, and converted them to timedelta prior to performing the sum.

Note the sum contains conditions, much like a COUNTIF statement in excel. You can modify the statement to add more conditions, or adjust the ones listed to get whatever output you're looking for.